# Unable to search by tags on mobile phone, it seems an old issue

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web

I am trying to search tags from search box but nothing happens. I am using iphone and tried with both chrome and safari but it doesn't works.

Comment: Do you mean you're on the "Tags" tab and using the filter option there to narrow down tags or you're trying to actually search for tags from the main search?

Comment: Yes i was on tag tab and searched by tapping on Magnifying glass icon.

Comment: I've sometimes had that on chrome on android - not sure what causes it or not but when it doesn't work try refreshing and making sure you're only typing things in lower case (ie - it's not auto-capitalising the first letter) and that sometimes works...

Comment: I tried by refreshing and typing in lower case too but then also it doesn't work.